# What is the most optimized way to create mesh from vertex web

Tags: vertices, optimization

I have this web of vertices that I want to convert into optimized mesh. When there is a big angle it goes smooth and when there is just a straight line it creates one "box" of vertices.
I tried skin modifier but it does not fit my needs.
The image might be able to say more than you can understand from this decription. I am still a beginner. I use Blender v2.79
I was thinking of using curves but need more help on that matter.
I have to have a box looking mesh along the lines so to use bevel on it.
[image: image of skin modifier used on 'web']

Comment: Could you explain a little more? What does the skin modifier do that you don't want to do, and what exactly are you trying to create?

Comment: Well I'm trying to create a web of mesh or something. I don't need the extra vertices, which the skin modifier creates, in my grid mesh. And when there is a 'turn' it has good quality interpolation, if that is the right word. I basically want to subdivide without creating too many vertices and not making the mesh round. http://prntscr.com/nvaocg